# Cloud Aware VS Cloud Based Applications

Tags: cloud

What will be the primary differences between Cloud Aware VS Cloud Based Applications ?

Are Cloud Based Applications purely applications deployed in cloud ?
What would be checklists for cloud aware application ? Is cloud awareness feature of the application or the cloud platform the application is deployed ?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should/are try to know the difference between Cloud Hosted vs Cloud Optimized vs Cloud Native

checkout this Gartner presentation http://www.gartner.com/webinar/3274118/player?commId=200333&channelId=5502&srcId=1-3478922244

Comment: That link has expired.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no differences between cloud aware applications and cloud based applications.

A cloud aware application is an application that is created with cloud in mind - for example, if I work with Microsoft Azure cloud (and I personally do) and I want to create cloud aware application, I should use mechanisms implented to Azure making me able to do it. These will be mechanisms such as virtual load balancers, availability sets (making VM's immune to hypervisor updates or hardware failures), autoscaling, VM image templating and auto-provisioning new servers on demand, automation, SQL as a service, or service bus (message query like RabbitMQ) as a service. Using cloud mechanism to build applications is lifting multi-tenant apps to higher level - especially with automation and resources scalability.

The second thing is cloud based application. In my opinion it is more business term nor technical one. If we speak about cloud based application, we have fact in mind, that it is remote app (on-line) and we are not managing infrastructure beneath this app. Cloud based application is some kind of replacement for on-premise application but lifted to unmanaged "cloud" somewhere into internet. We just using it not being aware about development, maintenance and resources it needs.